# Can't run Xamarin project after installing SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I installed `SkiaSharp` and `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms`
and when I used them in my code:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
            canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
            Content = canvasView;

        }


void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = Color.Red.ToSKColor(),
            StrokeWidth = 25
        };
        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);

        paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
        paint.Color = SKColors.Blue;
        canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);
    }
```

The project can't run, (the orange color of the debugging mode just disappear immediately), and there're no errors.

when I commented out the code above, the project run normally!
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4.5

I tried opening the project in VS 2015, I got this exception in MainActivity of the Android project at:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

Message:

> Specified cast is not valid.

StackTrace:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. at (wrapper
>   castclass) System.Object:__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr)
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar1[TRegistrable].GetHandler
>   (System.Type type) [0x0001b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:37
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar1[TRegistrable].GetHandler[TOut]
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:42
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00006] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:284
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean
>   sameChildren) [0x00023] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:86
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement
>   newElement) [0x00104] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:219
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:70
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer1[TElement].SetPackager
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager)
>   [0x00007] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:371
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer1[TElement].SetElement
>   (TElement element) [0x000ce] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:174
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:120
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:285
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean layout) [0x00015] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:268
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.SetPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot) [0x0007a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:245
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0009b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:337
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.SetMainPage
>   () [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:407
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Application application) [0x00229] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:152
>   at XamApp.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
>   [0x00028] in D :\P\XamApp\XamApp\XamApp.Android\MainActivity.cs:25

Answer (score 0):

To work, I have to install `SkiaSharp`, `SkiaSharp.Views`, and `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms` via nuget to the Android and iOS projects, PCL only requires `SkiaSharp` and `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms`.

original answer here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/310695/#Comment_310695